# Why was I able to send more than the apparent maximum amount of data via Bluetooth 4.2?

Tags: java, bluetooth

[My research showed](http://www.cypress.com/file/224826/download) (see pg. 5) that the maximum amount of data that can be sent via Bluetooth 4.2 is 257 bytes.

However, I was able to send 990 bytes between my Python script and Java application. Why was I able to send so much data? Is the information I found about the maximum data wrong, or did something else happen?

**Python Bluetooth script:**

```
        #Parameters config
        sdr=RtlSdr()
        sdr.fc=100e6
        sdr.gain=48
        sdr.rs=1.024e6

        #Bluetooth connection

        server_sock=BluetoothSocket(RFCOMM)
        server_sock.bind(("",PORT_ANY))
        server_sock.listen(1)

        port=server_sock.getsockname()[1]
        uuid="94f39d29-7d6d-437d-973b-fba39e49d4ee"
        client_sock,client_info=server_sock.accept()
 while (1):   
        samples= sdr.read_samples(256*1024)
        result=psd(samples, NFFT=70, Fc=sdr.fc/1e6, Fs=sdr.rs/1e6)
        tab_freq=(result[1])
        value_freq=str(tab_freq)[1:-1]
        value_freq2=[format(float(v),".4f")[:6] for v in value_freq.split()]
        value_freq3="\n".join(value_pxx2)

        #SAME FOR POWER VALUE
        #THEN I SEND DATA BY BLUETOOTH

        client_sock.send(value_freq3)
```

**Java Bluetooth code:**

```
private class ThreadConnected extends Thread {
        private final BluetoothSocket connectedBluetoothSocket;
        private final InputStream connectedInputStream;
        private final OutputStream connectedOutputStream;

        boolean running;

        public ThreadConnected(BluetoothSocket socket) {
            connectedBluetoothSocket = socket;
            InputStream in = null;
            OutputStream out = null;
            running = true;
            try {
                in = socket.getInputStream();
                out = socket.getOutputStream();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            connectedInputStream = in;
            connectedOutputStream = out;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1048576]; // 20 bits
            int bytes;
            String strRx = "";

            while (running) {
                try {
                    bytes = connectedInputStream.read(buffer);
                    final String strReceived_freq = new String(buffer,0, bytes/2);
                    final String strReceived_pxx = new String(buffer,(bytes/2)+1, bytes);
                    //final int samples_sdr=new Integer(buffer,0,bytes);
                    final String strByteCnt = String.valueOf(bytes) + " bytes received.\n";

                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){

                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                                Pxx_value.setText(strReceived_pxx+"\n");    // get data PXX
                                freq_value.setText(strReceived_freq+"\n"); // get data freq

                            // plot value
                          /*  for (int i=0; i<nb_points; i++)
                            {
                                freq[i]=Double.parseDouble(strReceived_freq);
                                pxx[i]=Double.parseDouble(strReceived_pxx);
                                series.appendData(new DataPoint(freq[i],pxx[i]), true,500);
                            }*/

                        }});

                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    cancel();

                    final String msgConnectionLost = "Connection lost:\n" + e.getMessage();
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){

                        @Override
                        public void run() {

                        }});
                }
            }
        }

        public void write(byte[] buffer) {
            try {
                connectedOutputStream.write(buffer);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        public void cancel() {
            running = false;
            try {
                connectedBluetoothSocket.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for this edit @CodyGray, it's really more clear now!

Comment: You're welcome! Thanks for sticking around and updating your question in response to feedback. If everyone would do that, things would go so much smoother. Hope you get a great answer!

Comment: I have just a supposition are you sure that the bluetooth device is not sending multiple plackets?

Comment: I don't know maybe you right but when I use this variable :  `final String strByteCnt = String.valueOf(bytes) + " bytes received.\n";` it give me all time 990 bytes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The document you link to shows the LE (low energy) Link Layer packet format, as specified in Vol 6, Part B, Section 2.1 of the Bluetooth Core Specification.

You are using RFCOMM, which is a Bluetooth Classic (aka BR/EDR) profile. The Link Layer packet format for BR/EDR is specified in Vol 2, Part B, Section 6 and shows that the payload can be up to 2790 bytes long.

In any case the API you are using doesn't give you access to the Link Layer. You are writing on an RFCOMM channel (which is designed to work more or less like a serial port) and you can write as many bytes as you want. Your library and the underlying platform will take care of placing your data into the appropriate number of L2CAP packets, which will then be further encapsulated in link layer packets. The main limitation you will run into are the buffer sizes in your implementation. In this case your socket based API will return the number of bytes that were written in the call to `send`, and you will be able to attempt retransmission later.

Comment: Thanks for this information ! I fixed the buffer size at `byte[] buffer = new byte[1048576]; // 20 bits`  It's enought normaly ?

Comment: Yes 1MB is more than enough for the reception buffer. I use 65535 which is the maximum L2CAP MTU but never reach it in my use case.

Comment: This is really strange because after approximaly 990 bytes, my value is erase by new value.

Comment: Can you elaborate? I didn't understand the issue. Also I had a look at the parsing code (`final String strReceived_freq = new String(buffer,0, 15*nb_points);`, etc). You should definitely not make the assumption that you will always receive the full packet in one call to read. Instead you should loop on the bytes in the buffer up to the `bytes` index, and copy the data elsewhere (in your case a `StringBuilder` for instance). When you determine that you have received the full packet, then update the UI.

Comment: yes sorry. I just edited. My variable is now `final String strReceived_freq=new String(buffer,0, bytes/2); ` I just edited too my script python to show you what type of data. I am actually try to send 2 types of value : Power value and frequency value. That's why I use `bytes/2`. Half of my value is power value so I send all of them and then I send all my frequency value.